# Perl: Can I store backreferences (not their values) in variables?

Tags: regex, perl

I'd like to do something like this:

```
my $text = "The owls are not what they seem.";  
my $pattern = '(\s+)';  
my $replacement = '-$1-';  
$text =~ s/$pattern/$replacement/g;
```

$text should then be: The- -owls- -are- -not- -what- -they- -seem.

But of course it's more like: The-$1-owls-$1-are-$1-not-$1-what-$1-they-$1-seem.

I tried all kinds of backreferences ($1, \1, \g{1}, \g1) and they all didn't
work. The /e modifier didn't work either. Is this possible at all?

The purpose is to alter some text inside an object with a line like this:
$object->replace('(.)oo', '$1ar')

Any other ideas how this could be done?

Thank you very much.

Comment: qr/(\s+)/ is better than '(\s+)'

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You could eval and then expand strings using `/ee`:

```
my $text = "The owls are not what they seem.";
my $pattern = '(\s+)';
my $replacement = q{"-$1-"};
$text =~ s/$pattern/$replacement/eeg;
```

From [perldoc perlop](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlop.html#s/PATTERN/REPLACEMENT/msixpogce):

> `e` Evaluate the right side as an expression.
>
> `ee` Evaluate the right side as a string then eval the result

However, I would feel safer with

```
my $replacement = sub { "-$1-" };
$text =~ s/$pattern/$replacement->()/eg;
```

But it all depends on the context in which you are doing this.

Comment: ee = Eval then expand variables.

Comment: I could have thought of the sub. It's so obvious now. And it fits perfectly. Thank you!

Answer (score 3):

Sinan Ünür's solution will work but it still requires the replacement string to be a literal inside the program at some point. If that replacement string comes from data, you'll have to do something a little fancier:

```
sub dyn_replace {
  my ($replace) = @_;
  my @groups;
  {
    no strict 'refs';
    $groups[$_] = $$_ for 1 .. $#-;      # the size of @- tells us the number of capturing groups
  }
  $replace =~ s/\$(\d+)/$groups[$1]/g;
  return $replace;
}
```

and then use it like

```
$text =~ s/$pattern/dyn_replace($replacement)/eg;
```

Note that this also avoids `eval` and allows the use of modifiers like /g. Code taken from [this Perl Monks node](http://www.perlmonks.org/?node_id=503934) but I wrote that node so it's ok :)

Comment: As far as I understand this it's somehow the same as Sinan Ünür's subref solution, except it's much more complicated.

Comment: Sinan's solution requires $replacement to be a literal string inside the subref. Mine allows it to be any arbitrary string value.

Answer (score -3):

$text =~ s/$pattern/-$1-/g;

Comment: No, I can't provide the '-$1-' part directly like this. It's inside a variable:  
$replacement = '-$1-';
$text =~ s/$pattern/$replacement/g;